# connecting bsnl data card in ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04

I have installed the BSNL 3G Modem sotware in ubuntu 12.04.4 64 bit, the same has been displayed in the Dash, but while cliking on the icon the program not getting invoked, no message also.
Any idea how to run this.

Answer (score 7):

First connect your Data Card to your PC. Then select the icon from the panel as shown below:

[image]

Then from the drop menu select `New Mobile Broadband Connection...` as shown below:

[image]

Then select your device from the dialog box that appears and then select `Continue`. My device is detected as `HSPADataCard`:

[image]

Then select your country and then select `Continue`:

[image]

Then select your ISP and then select `Continue`.(From your question it seems to be BSNL):

[image]

Then choose whichever billing plan you have opted for from the drop-down menu and then select `Continue`:

[image]

Then check if your configurations are right from the next dialog box and then select `Apply`.

[image]

Now you need to select `Save`:

[image]

Now you have successfully created a connection. All you need to do is just connect to the internet. There are two ways to do this:

- Select the same icon you selected at the beginning and then from the drop down menu select the `BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G 1`:

[image]

Then your PC will search for signal and then you will be connected to the internet :

[image]

[image]

(Forget about the time in the pictures! The screen shots where taken at different times.)

- The second method will be from the terminal. For opening the terminal press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd> . Now type:

  ```
  nmcli connection
  ```

Your output will be something like this:

```
    NAME                      UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Vodafone Vodafone Connect 1 e2419e6a-0df6-43a6-958c-4cc2602a271a   gsm               Wednesday 30 April 2014 07:32:39 PM IST
Airtel Default 1          b6028e87-3ac4-44d1-b7da-b6f8b8681fff   gsm               Wednesday 30 April 2014 08:58:27 PM IST
BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G 1 40906018-b388-40b7-8ce6-5d98ea487ca5   gsm               Thursday 08 May 2014 03:18:20 PM IST
Wired connection 1        6d9e5708-5901-4f53-9aa5-14bfd2712a0a   802-3-ethernet    Thursday 08 May 2014 11:13:20 AM IST
```

Now type in :

```
nmcli connection up uuid 40906018-b388-40b7-8ce6-5d98ea487ca5
```

(Note that after `uuid` I have just copied the UUID shown after the connection `BSNL/CellOne New GPRS/3G 1`)

Now you would have been connected to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Go to networking on the top panel in that you can find mobie broadband tick it on and there it will show your bsnl modem you can add the settings there.